How do I make each Instance (on Points) a different color?
How do I assign a random color to each instance created by the Instance on Points node?
(EDIT: The only solution I've found that would work is to "Realize Instances" as Chris pointed out below.  I want to find a solution that does not require this, if one exists, as converting many thousands of instances into unique objects would kill the viewport memory.)
This is the instance cloud created:

This is the node setup:

The closest I got to separating the colors is this Material node setup:


But I need the colors to be distributed completely at random.  How can I do this?
PROJECT FILE

I would have suggest the approach illustrated in this question (not the answer !) : How to convert a random color ramp material to a simple material for lots of object instances, reading from Blender 4.1 documentation that the Object Info node seems still to provide a randomized value per instance. But I have not checked myself for this version.

Since Blender version 3.5, you have two different options here...
Either you capture individual values in the instance domain with Store Named Attribute and use these values in your shader, for example with a Color Ramp:

Or you can enter the color you want in the instance domain directly in Geometry Nodes and use it in the shader:

Note: If you use the Attribute node in the shader, make sure that it is set to Instancer.

Thank you for this, it is very encouraging.  However, for some reason neither trick works for me, I just get an average of all the colors I'm using (in this case purple).  I will post a link to my new project file in case you'd like to take a look, thanks!

@GlenCandle In this case, make sure that you store the values in the Instance domain (and not in the Point domain).

That was it!  This works and looks beautiful, thanks so much!

@GlenCandle You are welcome!

just add the colored nodes here:

So basically you generate a random attribute from 0-1 per point. Important is the realize instances node.
Then in shader editor, use your generated random value for the input in your colorramp.
result:


Thanks Chris. The question was closed because someone else came up with the same solution in another post I had already found.  I should have mentioned that for memory purposes I don't want to realize instances, which would bog down the viewport with many thousands of objects.  Is there a way to do it without having to realize the instances?
